# How to remove add to compare button in Shopify (PORTO THEME)

Tags: compare, shopify, liquid

I want to remove add to compare button in Shopify.

I am using PORTO theme for shopify.

I can see there is a option **Disable AddToLink** , but if I do that Add to Wishlist button is also disappearing.

Can someone please help me with this?
If anyone has knowledge on Shopify or know Liquid.

Comment: you need to share the link of the website.

Comment: @Onkar have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @dgurtner not I don't look into it after it, need to check the Porto theme code for this, but I don't any customer that using it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme files, in the assets folder, look for `product.css` or `product.scss`, and at the very end of that file put `.product-view .actions .add-to-links li a.link-compare { display: none; }`.

Either this or look for the HTML tag inside the `product.liquid` file and remove it.

```
<li>
<a href="javascript:;" data-product-handle="blue-high-hill" data-product-title="Blue High Hill" class="link-compare" title="Add to compare">
<i class="icon-compare"></i>
<span data-translate="compare_list.general.add_to_compare">Add to compare</span></a
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme file,inside the Assets folder find out the **styles.scss** file.Inside this file search this line **.product-view .product-options-bottom .add-to-cart-box ul li** and add below line after this search css line.

.product-view .product-options-bottom .add-to-cart-box ul li:last-child { display: none; }

Also you can add inline css for that one in product page.the file name is product-template.liquid and this file inside **section**.
In product-template file find out below code and add inline css in **li** Tag.
Add this one in li tag **style="display:none"**

```html
<li><a href="javascript:;" data-product-handle="porto-extended-camera" data-product-title="Porto Extended Camera" class="link-compare" title="Add to compare"><i class="icon-compare"></i><span data-translate="compare_list.general.add_to_compare">Add to compare</span></a></li>
```

It's work very well ,if you any other issues related this comment it.

Answer (score 0):

In Porto theme, you would check in the `\snippets\product-grid-item.liquid` file.

You would come across something like this in several places:

```
{% if settings.collection_show_addtolinks != blank and product.variants.size <= 1 %}
  <div class="action-list">
    {% if settings.wishlist_enable %}
    <div class="product-wishlist wishlist-{{product.id}}">
      <a href="javascript:;" data-product-handle="{{product.handle}}" data-product-title="{{product.title}}" class="link-wishlist" title="{{'wish_list.general.add_to_wishlist' | t}}"><i class="icon-wishlist"></i><span {% if settings.language_enable %}data-translate="wish_list.general.add_to_wishlist"{% endif %}>{{ 'wish_list.general.add_to_wishlist' | t }}</span></a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

So you just move the wishlist code outside of the `if` statement...

```
{% if settings.collection_show_addtolinks != blank and product.variants.size <= 1 %}
  <div class="action-list">
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% if settings.wishlist_enable %}
<div class="product-wishlist wishlist-{{product.id}}">
  <a href="javascript:;" data-product-handle="{{product.handle}}" data-product-title="{{product.title}}" class="link-wishlist" title="{{'wish_list.general.add_to_wishlist' | t}}"><i class="icon-wishlist"></i><span {% if settings.language_enable %}data-translate="wish_list.general.add_to_wishlist"{% endif %}>{{ 'wish_list.general.add_to_wishlist' | t }}</span></a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Then just `{% comment %}...{% endcomment %}` or delete whatever you don't want to keep.